# I am trying to apply the @class values to my Actionlink butit does not work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

```
@Html.ActionLink("DETAIL", "block_detail", "Home", new { id = u.Id , @class="btn btn-primary", style="border-radius:20px;" }, null)
```

This is how i am doing it.

Comment: The 4th paramater is the route values. You need to add it in the 5th parameter.

Comment: Should i place null there?

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("DETAIL", "block_detail", "Home", new { id = u.Id }, new { @class="btn btn-primary", style="border-radius:20px;" })`

Comment: can u share html rendered